# Resize image if necessary to fit in fixed height container

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is there anyway with CSS and/or JavaScript/jQuery that we can resize images *only* if they need to be for the remaining content to fit in a fixed-height container? If you review the images in the *new this week* and *weekly specials* sections in the screenshot below you'll see what I mean. There are some instances, however, where everything fits because the image is small enough and the amount of text below them isn't very large.

[image: See example here]

Comment: Your images should have normalized heights in the first place. I'd resize them serverside.

Comment: Can you provide some HTML, and css as examples?

Comment: We do resize the images on the server-side, but this particular client uses different sizes for different types of products. Dresses, for example, are taller than shirts as you can see in the screenshot. I know I can easily normalize the heights dynamically on the server-side, but I was curious if there was another way using CSS and/or jQuery that would only resize if necessary.

You can see the HTML source @ http://www.milknursingwear.com

Answer (score 2):

With jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() { $('div.item img').each(function() {
    var image = $(this);
    var div = $('div.item p');
    if ((image.height() + div.height()) >> $('div.item').height()) {
        while ((image.height() + div.height()) >> $('div.item').height()) {
            image.height(image.height() - 1);
        }
    }
});});
```

Comment: That's a really interesting solution! Would this maintain the proper proportions of the image? Also - do you know how well this works in IE7 and IE8? I can certainly test, but just curious. Thanks so much!

Comment: @ShawnCBerg - I edited the answer one more time and as for those two questions, I believe it will work the same in IE7, IE8

Answer (score 2):

No, not with CSS only as you are describing. But yes, with jQuery you can accomplish this.

I'm not efficient enough with jQuery personally to attempt to give you an coded solution, but conceptually you could do something like check for the calculated height of the child elements combined, and then match that up against the parent container's height. Then if the child elements are larger than the fixed element's height, calculate the difference and add that new value onto the image as an inline height attribute, or as an inline style attribute.

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with setting the max-height CSS property?

```
<img src="big.jpg" style="max-height:300px">
```

and then add a CSS expression to workaround IE6

```
<img src="big.jpg" style="max-height:300px; _height:expression(Math.min(this.offsetHeight, 300))">
```

Comment: Because the max-height varies depending upon the amount of text that is displayed below the image.